# How do I compile 64bit program with gcc/g++ on a 64bit Linux?

Tags: linux, 64-bit, gcc, g++

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, and want to make a program to run on a large Debian server that has 300GB memory. With command:

```
g++ Encoder.cpp -std=c++0x -m64 -o Encoder.o
```

it returns something like

```
In files included from /usr/include/features.h:378,
                  from /usr/include/c++/4.4/i486-linux-gnu/64/bits/os_defines.h:39
                  from /usr/include/c++/4.4/i486-linux-gnu/64/bits/c++confige.h:243,
                  from /usr/include/c++/4.4/iostream:39,
                  from Encoder.cpp:1:
/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:9:27: error: gnu/stubs-64.h: No such file or directory
```

but without the -m64 flag, the program is compilable, but will run into "segmentation fault" problem whenever RAM usage is over about 2.5GB.

Or would actually the default compilation be 64bit? How do I tell if a process is 32bit or 64bit in "top"?

Comment: The error is clear; a header file cannot be found; you need to supply it to compile the program

Comment: Why did you post this to both Super User and [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25954595/3938807)? I think Stack Overflow is probably the better of the two in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The `glibc-devel` package should be correct, however, be sure to use the x86_64 arch package.

In my fedora, `glibc-devel.x86_64` was the correct package.

For ubuntu, it might be simply `glibc-dev.x86_64`

Try one of the following

```
sudo apt-get install glibc-devel.x86_64

sudo apt-get install glibc-dev.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks you're missing the `glibc-devel` package that carries `gnu/stubs-64.h`. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install glibc-devel
```